B1/B2 Dual nationality Visa refused?
I have dual nationality: Iranian, the country that I born in, and Netherlands where I've been living for quite some time. I had a visa interview with the consular section as I am not eligible for ESTA program due to my Iranian background, but the officer refused my application and told me they have to do some checks and if the decision changes they will notify me.
Do they really progress with my application any further?

My guess is that this is standard procedure and that the chance of the visa being granted in the end is pretty good.
